# Jquery how to load new page in a dialog box

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am new to jquery and i was wondering whats the best way to load a new page in a dialog or something similar for instance.

```
<a href="~/article/@item.ArticleID" ">Click To View Page</a>
```

I would Like if someone where to click on the link above a dialog page will show up with the new pages content. I have many different articles on my page that way users can skim through them and still stay in the same page.. any pointers would be great !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code this on the click event event of `a` tag with specific `id`.

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(selector).load(URL,data,callback);
```

like this

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

or 
[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("page.html", function(data) {
  $("#div").html(data);
});
```